# How to implement the web3 in react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, web3js

In my project using react-native, I want to use web3.

But I'm unsure of how to use Web3 with React Native.

Answer (score 0):

***https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web3-wallet?activeTab=readme***

**seems to be working as of 2023/03 rn -v@0.71.4**

***Installation (goes with YARN as well):***

```
npm install github:heroims/react-native-web3-wallet --save
npm install @ethersproject/shims --save
npm install react-native-get-random-values --save
npx pod-install
npm install react-native-scrypt@1.2.1
npm install react-native-aes-crypto@2.1.1
npm install patch-package
```

**then run this codes to patch** (in the root directory of your app):

```
mkdir patches
copy node_modules\react-native-web3-wallet\patches\* patches\
npx patch-package
```

**Before crating a wallet, insert this line in the top of your index.js entry file**

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
```

***to create a wallet the following code seems to be working as well:***

```
  import {createWallet,exportMnemonicFromKeystore} from 'react-native-web3-wallet';

  // Generate a new wallet with a randomly generated mnemonic phrase
  const wallet = await createWallet('YOUR_PASSWORD')
  console.log('wallet.keystore',wallet.keystore)

  // Export the mnemonic phrase so you can use it to import the wallet later if needed
  const mnemonic = await exportMnemonicFromKeystore(JSON.stringify(wallet.keystore), 'YOUR_PASSWORD')
  .then(res=>{
    console.log(`Mnemonic phrase: ${res}`);
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log("\x1b[31m",`Mnemonic ERROR: ${err}`);
  })
```

Please dont forget to check the library to see if everything is upToDate

Answer (score 0):

There are some unofficial solutions for using web3js with the help of Web View in react native.
But the official way is to use [Walletconnect for ReactNative](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/advanced/walletconnectmodal/about) which is being maintained by the community and it's using Wagmi library at its core in the latest version.